# Need support with one time alertcondition after trend switch

Tags: pine-script, trend

I am new in pine script and wants to have an one time alert in case of an trend switch (green to red and red to green).

Who can help me to have alerts for this script?

```
//@version=4
study("Hilo script with alert",overlay=true)
period=input(10,"Period")
shift=input(1,"Shift")
exp=input(false,"EMA")
max=exp?ema(high[shift],period):sma(high[shift],period)
min=exp?ema(low[shift],period):sma(low[shift],period)
pos=close>max?-1:close<min?1:0
pos:=pos==0?nz(pos[1]):pos
hilo=pos==1?max:min
plotbar(hilo,hilo,hilo,hilo,color=pos==1?color.red:color.green)
```

Thanks a lot for all your help in advance

My idea was this:

```
sell = pos:=1
buy = pos==1
alertcondition(sell,title='sell', message='sell')
alertcondition(buy,title='buy', message='buy')
```

but I get every candle an alert. And this isnt that what i want.

After and research in the internet I was able to find this:

```
// Deternine if we are currently LONG
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)
// Determine if we are currently SHORT
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)
// Buy if the buy signal is triggered and we are not already long
buySignal = not isLong
// Sell if the sell signal is triggered and we are not already short
sellSignal= not isShort
if (buySignal)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false
if (sellSignal)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true
alertcondition(buySignal,title='buy',message='buy')
alertcondition(sellSignal,title='sell', message='sell')
```

But Iam getting some errors in Tradingview:

```
//@version=4
study("Hilo script with alertr",overlay=true)
period=input(8,"Period")
shift=input(1,"Shift")
exp=input(false,"Exponential moving average")
max=exp?ema(high[shift],period):sma(high[shift],period)
min=exp?ema(low[shift],period):sma(low[shift],period)
pos=close>max?-1:close<min?1:0
isLong:=pos==0?nz(pos[1]):pos
isShort=pos==1?max:min
plotbar(isShort,isShort,isShort,isShort,color=pos==1?color.red:color.green)

// Deternine if we are currently LONG
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)

// Determine if we are currently SHORT
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)

// Buy only if the buy signal is triggered and we are not already long
buySignal = not isLong

// Sell only if the sell signal is triggered and we are not already short
sellSignal= not isShort

if (buySignal)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

alertcondition(sellSignal,title='sell', message='sell')
alertcondition(buySignal,title='buy', message='buy')
```

after your valueable feedback I adapt this lines:

```
isLong=pos==0?nz(pos[1]):pos
isShort=pos==1?max:min
plotbar(isShort,isShort,isShort,isShort,color=pos==1?color.red:color.green)

// Deternine if we are currently LONG
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)

// Determine if we are currently SHORT
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)
```

Now Iam getting in Line 14 an error marked with >>>>:

```
// Deternine if we are currently LONG
>>>>isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#alerts) page.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Something like this?

Comment: Please don't add new information as a comment. Instead, edit your post. Did you try this code on Tradingview?

Comment: No one with any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Processing script...
line 9: Undeclared identifier `isLong`;
line 18: Variable `isShort` is already declared.
Script 'Hilo script with alertr' has been saved

Comment: Well, error messages are clear. You should use `=` operator to declare variables. You should use `:=` operator to reassign values to variables that are already defined.

Comment: At line 9, you have `:=` operator but this is actually defining a variable, hence you should use `=` instead. At line 18, you have `=` operator, but `isShort` is already defined at line 10. You should use `:=` operator instead, at line 18.

Comment: So again, use `=` when you **first** declare a variable. Use `:=` next time when you want to assign some value to previously defined variables.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now Iam adapted this script and getting in Line 14 marked with >>>>> in my descripton above!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `=` operator only when you **declare** a variable. After that, when you want to assign some value to a variable, you should use `:=` operator.

If you use the `=` operator to assign values to a previously defined variable, you will get the following error:

> line x: Variable `xxx` is already declared.

If you use the `:=` operator without declaring a variable, you will get the following error:

> line x: Undeclared identifier `xxx`;

This script will trigger alerts only once. To see that, I have added two `plotshape()`s.

```
//@version=4
study("Hilo script with alert",overlay=true)
period=input(10,"Period")
shift=input(1,"Shift")
exp=input(false,"EMA")

var isLong = false
var isShort = false

max=exp?ema(high[shift],period):sma(high[shift],period)
min=exp?ema(low[shift],period):sma(low[shift],period)

buySignal = not isLong and (close >= max)       // Buy when close >= max and we are not already long
sellSignal = not isShort and (close < min)      // Sell when close < min and we are not already short

if (buySignal)          // Set the flags for buy condition
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal)         // Set the flags for sell condition
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

plotshape(series=buySignal, text="BUY", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=sellSignal, text="SELL", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small)

alertcondition(buySignal, title="BUY", message="BUY")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="SELL", message="SELL")
```

[image]

As you can see, the script only plots "BUY" or "SELL" whenever your indicator changes color.